# Does the performance change when I switch Distinct() and OrderBy() in a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, expression-trees

I am just considering which provides me the best performance when I use both `OrderBy()` and `Distinct()` inside a LINQ Query. It seems to me they're both equal in speed as the `Distinct()` method will use a hash table while in-memory and I assume that any SQL query would be optimized first by .NET before it gets executed.
Am I correct in assuming this or does the order of these two commands still affect the performance of LINQ in general?
As for how it would work... When you build a LINQ query, you're basically building an expression tree but nothing gets executed yet. So calling `MyList.Distinct().OrderBy()` would just make this tree, yet won't execute it. (It's deferred.) Only when you call another function like `ToList()` would the expression tree get executed and the runtime could optimize the expression tree before it gets executed.

Comment: "I assume that any SQL query would be optimized first by .NET before it gets executed" -- you assume wrongly. LINQ queries will be translated and optimized  by the provider. They will not be optimized or rewritten by the runtime, as that could affect the fidelity of the result. Any conclusions you might draw from how LINQ to Objects executes a query are null and void if the query ends up with a database provider, where the database engine's rules apply.

Comment: Even with LINQ to Objects, `.Distinct().OrderBy()` and `.OrderBy().Distinct()` are different sequences of operations with different outcomes and different performance characteristics. Consider applying both to a collection of 10 000 identical values, then a collection of 10 000 distinct values, to see why.

Comment: First define the playing field. LINQ-to-object and LINQ to a SQL backend are completely different things. This question can't be answered if we don't know what we're talking about.

Comment: Actually we can. LINQ to SQL is ancient technology that I think neve rmade id to .NET core - and that is tagged.

Comment: @TomTom: but it's not? `linq` (the general technology) is not `linq-to-sql`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert THat would be EXTREMELY confusing given that LINQ2SQL was - a ORM technology a little before EntityFramework and that i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/ the ms docs refer to LINQ to SQL as a component of .NET framework 3.5 that... is an ORM.

Comment: @TomTom: Oh, I see now, you were responding to Gert specifically. Probably best if you'd tagged him. Yes, LINQ to SQL is excluded by `.net-core`; I interpreted your remark as saying the *question* was tagged as LINQ to SQL. Of course the point is a quibble, Gert's remark still applies if you replace "LINQ to SQL" with any specific LINQ provider that is translated to SQL and *is* supported on Core. (Including but not limited to EF.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thing is, the OrderBy() method doesn't remove any data, but Distinct() does. So Distinct() before OrderBy() seems to suggest that OrderBy() gets less data. So, you have a point here. However, Linq doesn't really execute anything until you start requesting data so it's not optimizing it?

Comment: Deferred execution is not really relevant in this scenario, unless you're planning to chain more operations that might allow for the `OrderBy()` and/or `Distinct()` to be eliminated (but LINQ to Objects doesn't work that way; it mostly executes operations in order, with only a few clever tricks here and there to optimize combinations of operations). Suppose a provider was implemented in such a way that `.Distinct()` was always guaranteed to give its results already sorted; such a provider could eliminate the `.OrderBy()` entirely. But it would be unusual, and couldn't be guaranteed in general.

Comment: The bottom line is simply this: it is not true that `.OrderBy().Distinct()` should always be preferred over `.Distinct().OrderBy()` or vice versa, for reasons of performance, if the question is applied to LINQ providers in general, because it depends on the provider. Only when you pick a particular provider (be it LINQ to Objects, Entity Framework on SQL Server, or anything else) can you start answering questions about performance. As for *correctness*, it's pretty simple: if you didn't end things in `.OrderBy()`, you may not have an ordered result -- whether that matters is up to you.

Comment: High level ridiculous extreme: you have an array of 1 million random ints between 1 and 10. Do you you think it will be quicker to reduce them to an array of 10 ints then sort 10 ints, or will it be quicker to sort the million and then throw 999,990 away?

Comment: @CaiusJard: and to illustrate why it's so important to know what provider is involved (and what it's working with) consider a table with 1 million random ints between 1 and 10 that just happens to have a columnstore index on those values. Both sequences of operations essentially involve simply scanning the index segments, except that `.Distinct().OrderBy()` must present the results in order. if you start increasing the "10" `.OrderBy().Distinct()` may well become faster because it is not required to order the end results, thereby allowing for maximum parallelism. Topsy turvy!

Comment: I return here after 12 hours. As expected, this whole Q&A has turned into a muddle of comments because nobody knows what OP wants and others mix in their own ill-informed assumptions (which is basically what the question consists of in the first place). Typically a "needs more focus" question. Jeroen nailed it in his very first comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it leads too too many discussions instead of a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LINQ to objects even if we assume that that `OrderBy(...).Distinct()` and `Distinct().OrderBy(...)` will return the same result ([which is not guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks)) the performance will depend on the data.

If you have a lot of duplication in data - running `Distinct` first should be faster. Next benchmark shows that (at least on my machine):

```
public class LinqBench
{
    private static List<int> test = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i, 10))
        .Select((i, index) => (i, index))
        .OrderBy(t => t.index % 10)
        .Select(t => t.i)
        .ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public List<int> OrderByThenDistinct() => test.OrderBy(i => i).Distinct().ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public List<int>  DistinctThenOrderBy()=> test.Distinct().OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
}
```

On my machine for .Net Core 3.1 it gives:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OrderByThenDistinct | 129.74 us | 2.120 us | 1.879 us |
| DistinctThenOrderBy | 19.58 us | 0.384 us | 0.794 us |

Comment: This benchmark does show quite a difference, which does surprise me. But have you tried doing the same benchmark with DistinctThenOrderBy first, then OrderByThenDistinct? After all, it could be that the database server has been caching data...

Comment: @WimtenBrink the benchmark I'm showing is for LINQ to Objects, there is no database. As for databse query - LINQ code will be transformed into SQL and how it is transformed will hugely depend on the concrete query, ORM and database provider. And then there is database engine which also can optimize the query. To many unknows for me to create a benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

First, `seq.OrderBy(...).Distinct()` and `seq.Distinct().OrderBy(...)` are not guaranteed to return the same result, because `Distinct()` [may return an unordered enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads). MS implementation conveniently preserves the order, but if you pass a LINQ query to the database, the results may come back in any order the DB engine sees fit.

Second, in the extreme case when you have lots of duplication (say, five values repeated randomly 1,000,000 times) you would be better off doing a `Distinct` before `OrderBy()`.

Long story short, if you want your results to be ordered, use `Distinct().OrderBy(...)` regardless of the performance.

Comment: That is possibly an oversight, except documentation.. A Distinct().OrderBy() in LINQ would HAVE TO materialize the Distinct results and make a select over this (on SQL SERver) with an OrderBy to make sure the result is ordered. THat said, you link the wong documentation.

Comment: You link to the wrong documentation - the right one is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Distinct__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__ which handles this specifically for LINQ. Your reference talks of Enumrable - this is Queryable.

Comment: @TomTom: `Distinct().OrderBy()` isn't the problem, `OrderBy().Distinct()` is. The former is guaranteed to be ordered, the latter is not. This is certainly true on the SQL side as well (`DISTINCT` with no `ORDER BY` follow-up has no intrinsic order, even if operating on already sorted data).

Comment: @TomTom LINQ query could refer to `IEnumerable<T>` or to `IQueryable<T>`. In fact, OP even discusses in-memory performance in his question when he mentions hash-based implementation of `Distinct`.

Comment: No. He says he uses it in memory and asks about SQL That implies IQueryable at least for the SQL part because otherwise there would be no sense in any SQL optimization as the query would be materialized already.

Comment: Guys, I'm asking in general and not just SQL-based or other ORM-based. Linq is used in many ways and I want to be sure that Distinct().OrderBy() should always be used instead of the reverse. (A colleague of mine disagrees. :D )

Comment: Well, there are 2 LINQ implementation - one is generating code, one is generating a semantic tree and THAT IS IT - it then hands this object node tree over to whoever implements the IQueryable to do with it what it wants. There is no magic central standard in LINQ for processing the tree.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that any SQL query would be optimized first by .NET before it gets >
> executed.

And how do you think that would work, given that:

- Only the SQL executing side (the server) has the knowledge for this (i.e. which indices to use) AND has a query optimizer that is supposed to optimize the executed query based on the statistics of the table.
- You have to be VERY sure that you do not change the result in any way.

Sorry, this makes no sense - there are pretty much no optimizations that you CAN safely do in C# without having all the internal details of the database, so the query is sent to the database for analysis.

As such, an OrderBy or a Distinct (ESPECIALLY a distinct) WILL impact performance - how much depends on i.e. whether the OrderBy can rely on an index.

> or does the order of these two commands still affect the performance of LINQ
> in general?

Here it gets funny (and you give no example).

DISTINCT and ORDERBY are in SQL in a specific order, regardless how you formulated it in LINQ. There is only ONE allowed syntax as per SQL definition. LINQ puts the query together and optimizes that out. If you look at the syntax, there is a specific place for the DISTINCT (which is a SQL term for at least SQL Server) and the OrderBy.

On the other side...

.Distinct().OrderBy() and .OrderBy().Distinct()

have DIFFERENT RESULTS. They CAN be done in SQL (you can use the output of the Distinct as a virtual table that you then order), but they have a different semantic. Unless you think that LINQ will magically read your mind, there is no context for the compiler other than to assume you are competent in writing what you do (as long as it is legal) and execute these steps in the order you gave.

Except: The DOCUMENTATION for Distinct in Queryable is clear this is not done:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Distinct__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__

says that Distinct returns an unordered list.

So, there is a fundamental difference and they are not the same.

Comment: You do realize that while the server would execute the query, it's still LINQ that creates the query. When it collects the data to make the query, it could exchange the order of both commands, if need be, to improve performance.

Comment: @WimtenBrink: it is the query provider implementation that performs the translation, not "LINQ" in general, and while it is technically possible for something like a SQL provider to rearrange operations wholesale, in practice they don't bother because this won't speed anything up while introducing quite some potential for bugs. In this case, `.Distinct().OrderBy()` *may not* be rearranged to `.OrderBy().Distinct()` as order would not be preserved, while the opposite operation might perform very differently and it would be foolish to preemptively second-guess the engine.

Comment: "You do realize that while the server would execute the query, it's still LINQ that creates the query" - no. The query is a tree of nodes that is handed over to the provider, LINQ does not do anything else than generate the filter tree. "When it collects the data to make the query, " - except it is NOT collecting data, neither is the translator as this would impose a very significant overhead - given that the general assumption is that this is not running ON The server so latency is an issue. There is no "gathering".